# Is it possible to play multiple games with Stockfish simultaneously?

Tags: stockfish

I am asking this because Stockfish was accepting different FEN strings through the terminal inbetween a game, of which it is giving best moves. I have compiled Stockfish in the Ubuntu 19.04 terminal.

Comment: How do you know it was giving best moves btw?

Comment: bcoz that what it does. hahaha, for that, you need to understand how these chess engines thinks, hopefully after studying this, all your doubts will be cleared.

Comment: Chess engines are extremely strong but they don't come close to always giving the best moves.

Comment: i'm not sure about it

Comment: Maybe this can help : http://web.ist.utl.pt/diogo.ferreira/papers/ferreira13impact.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chessbase you can have Stockfish analyzing/playing in multiple boards. It's definitely possible to do this, but it slows Stockfish down since it's being overworked. So it'll take longer to search ahead in each game.

Comment: what are your thoughts on this :
https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/26501/20128